# A PHP Toolkit of some functions

Tags: php, security, hashcode

Any major security risks? And please don't get angry over my novice log system.

```
<?php
   function makesalt($lg)
    {
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()-';  
    $sz = strlen( $chars );
    $str = '';
    for( $i = 0; $i < $lg; $i++ ) {
        $str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $sz - 1 ) ];
    }
    return $str;
  }
  function duelsha($th)
  {
      $tem = hash('sha512', $th);
      $tem2 = md5($tem);
      return hash('sha256', $tem2);
  }
  function shasalt($ht)
  {
      $salt = makesalt(30);
      return duelsha($ht . $salt) . '|' . $salt;
  }
  function mysqlsan($ss)
  {
      if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $ss = stripslashes($ss);
      return mysql_real_escape_string($ss);
  }
  function htent($st)
  {
      return htmlentities($st);
  }
  function sqlhtml($sm)
  {
       return htent(mysqlsan($sm));
  }
  function logs($tl)
  {
    $fh = fopen("server.log", 'w') or die("File error");
    fwrite($fh, $tl) or die("File error");
    fclose($fh);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You home brewed security hashes and such are a big **NO**. Please, [check here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25585/is-my-developers-home-brew-password-security-right-or-wrong-and-why) and [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) for a good read regarding that. Also, please do not hash a hash, that can lead to collisions and should be avoided! Using a method such as `password_hash()` creates a salt for you, therefore you shouldn't have to make one on your own.

You're using `mysql_real_escape_string()` which is not the way to go. If possible, move away from that and onto mysqli or PDO.

And then your function `htent()` is sort of redundant. You don't have anything else in the function, so it shouldn't be needed.